# Javascript event to know when a user changes something on a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which has:

- two input text fields
- 4 selects
- 1 textarea

Is there an easy way to capture the following event?

When a user types inside the input fields, or selects something from the list, or types something inside the text area?

Or do I have to do it the old fashion way like: do a change function for the select, on focus for the input and so on?

Basically, I want to be able to know when something changes on the form.

Any ideas?

**Here is an update:**

**Lets say I use the following code:**

```
$('input, textarea, select').on('change', function() {
    console.log('hey');

    // how do I unbind this certain even after the first "hey" listing of the console?

});
```

How do I unbind this certain even after the first listing of the console?

Comment: `$("#myform *).change(function(){ . . . })`.

Comment: Wow, really, that easy?:)) It's like not seeing the forest because of the trees... lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find when an `input` element changes, we can simply do the following:

```
$('input').change(function(){
    console.log('Something has changed');
});
```

That will capture all the events on all the `input` elements on the page, but in your case we have the following:

- two input text fields
- 4 selects
- 1 textarea

The `input` selector won't match all of those. However, **don't panic**! We can still do this. The clever thing is that, in the DOM, all ancestor elements are notified of events that occur on their ancestors. For example, a click on a `span` inside a `div` will notify both elements that the click has occurred.

So in this case we just need to find a common ancestor element that contains all these elements, and capture the event on that. The obvious one to use is the `form`:

```
$('form').change(function(){
    console.log('Something has changed');
});
```

**However** this may not be the best we can do. For instance, it would nice to have a quick way to access the element that was changed. It would also be nice if we could ensure that no other elements could trigger the function. jQuery makes this possible for us with the `on` function. This allows us to attach the handler to the `form` element and make sure that the originating element matches a selector, and then gives us a reference to that element as `this` from inside the function.

This code could look like this:

```
$('form').on('change', 'input, select, textarea', function() {
    console.log('Something has changed in an element called ' + this.name;
});
```

---

Your edit suggests you want to be able to disable the handler at some point.

There are two ways to do this. The first is simple and crude:

```
$('form').off('change');
```

No more `change` events will be captured on `form`. If you want to re-enable it, however, you have to go through the whole rigmarole of re-binding the event handler. The other option is to have a variable that tells you whether the event handler should be enabled or not:

```
var enabled = true;
$('form').on('change', 'input, select, textarea', function() {
    if (enabled) {
        console.log('Something has changed in an element called ' + this.name;
    }
});
```

You can then disable the handler by setting `enabled` to `false`, and re-enable it by setting it to `true` again.

Comment: I have update the question, can you please take a look and give me your input?

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
$('input, textarea, select').on('change', function() {
     alert('something\'s changed!');
});
```

where 'input' is each of your input elements (or a class name that is shared by the ones that you want to track)

Comment: $('input, textarea, select') would be more appropriate to match all form elements.

Comment: One more thing, can I bind and unbind the change function?

Comment: I have update the question, can you please take a look and give me your input?

Answer (score 1):

does this work for you?

```
$(":input").change(function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$("#myform *:input").change(function(){
    // do stuff here!
});
```

to add change to everything 'input-like' in `#myform`.

**Added:** As for unbinding, use:

```
$('#myform *:input').on('change', function() {
    console.log('hey');

    $('#myform *:input').off('change', arguments.callee);

});
```

Real Easy

Answer (score 0):

Assign data on focus, check data on blur:

```
$('#FormName').on({
    focus:function(){
        $(this).data('curval',$(this).val());
    },
    blur:function(){
        if($(this).val() !== $(this).data('curval')){
            alert('changed!');
        }
    }
},'input,select,textarea');
```

This should be pretty universal, and performant with the delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
//For a dropdown list/select
$( "#select" ).change(function() {
    dostuff
});

//For a textbox AS the user enters keystrokes (as opposed to on end of focus)
$( "#text" ).on('input', function() {
    dostuff
});
```